# error: cannot find symbol variable db

Tags: android, database, variables, insert

How can I fix this problem? I checked all libs but I cannot solve.  I added comments to the lines.

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + ifade + " TEXT," + yorum + " TEXT"+")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

public void addanswer(String ifadestring,String yorumstring)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ifade, ifadestring);
    values.put(yorum, yorumstring);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values); //ERROR cannot find symbol variable db
    db.close(); //ERROR cannot find symbol variable db
}
```

Comment: You must declare what `db` is in your method. Does the class which owns this methods contain `db` field? Compiler is telling you NOPE, you haven't defined what `db` is.

Comment: your `addanswer` has no `db`, and there is no magical way it will understand by itself what you want the `db` to be. You are missing `java` basics.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your db file having extension .db or something and you place it on assest folder in android packages

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
public void AnkatorEkle(String ifadestring,String yorumstring)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ifade, ifadestring);
    values.put(yorum, yorumstring);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```